# How to get a value from an anonymous class?

Tags: java, android

I want to get a value from anonymous class like this,but it always show nothing about `test0`, can anyone help me with this ?

```
        final String[] test = new String[1];
        txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                test[0] = "abc";
            }
        });
        String test0 = test[0];
        Toast.makeText(this, test0, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Have you checked answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value for `test[0]` will only be available after the `View` has been clicked. Your code does not wait for that. Move the `Toast` inside the `ClickListener` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `Toast` inside of the `setOnClickListener()` otherwise it won't see the changes on `test[]`

```
final String[] test = new String[1];
txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      test[0] = "abc";
      Toast.makeText(this, test[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your listener to include showing toast message inside `onClick()` method because you want to show that value when "click" occurs. Otherwise value of `test0` is not being updated outside of that method:

```
final String[] test = new String[1]; txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        test[0] = "abc";
        String test0 = test[0];
        Toast.makeText(this, test0, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this change

```
    final String[] test = new String[1];
    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            test[0] = "abc";
            Toast.makeText(this, test[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

The the value of test[0] is updated only after the a click event is fired. So you need to place your code inside the onClick method.